# Stripes options-collection init behaviour

Tags: java, stripes

I'm making a registration form that has a dropdown list for the users qualification. My actionbean has a String[] qualifs attribute with getter and setter, from which i'd like to fill the list from. It works fine, but only after i push the ok button and call the actionbean. Is this the normal behaviour, and if so, is there any way to initialize the list data when my jsp loads the first time?
The relevant snippet:

```
<stripes:select name="qualification">
  <stripes:option value="">Select</stripes:option>
  <stripes:options-collection collection="${actionBean.qualifs}"/>
</stripes:select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you're loading a JSP directly, without goind through a Stripes action before? If so, don't do that. It goes agains the MVC pattern. The action bean should be invoked, prepare the data neeed by the view, and then forward to the view.

Comment: Yes, i did so. Thank you, i wasn't aware of that. May i ask, how could i open my jsp from the AB (is there a special named method i should place the initializing and forwarding stuff into)?

Comment: No. You can chose the method name you want.

Comment: And how would stripes know that it should open my jsp page (from the beanclass binding)?
Actually, if there's a site that explains it, it would be nice, i don't want to steal your time :)

Comment: Just like with every other stripes action. You create a method returning a Resolution. In this method, you prepare the data for the view. And at the end, you return a ForwardResolution with the path of the JSP to forward to. http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide

Comment: There's one thing i still don't understand: the stripes examples contain lots of links to the jsp-s, not to the actions. For example, the starter index.html links to jsp-s, and i only see actionbeans in the stripes forms.

Comment: Then they're bad examples. The second best practice listed in http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Best+Practices explicitely says: *HTTP requests should generally not be sent to JSPs directly*

Comment: Thank you very much! Now my application works as it should.